# How to Invoke Admin Level Authorized Azure HTTP Trigger Function

Tags: azure-functions, postman, azure-java-sdk, azure-http-trigger

I've Created HttpTrigger Azure Java Functions with ADMIN LEVEL Authorization:

[image: Function Screenshot in azure Portal]

Reference Document Link: https://vincentlauzon.com/2017/12/04/azure-functions-http-authorization-levels/

For Invoking Admin Authorized Azure Function, we need Host Keys from Function App so, I have Three Host keys In Function App
[image: HostKeys]

Invoking Function URL in Postman with Function App Host key & Value in Header Section

1. Invoking with _master key and Value
   [image: _master key results]
2. Invoking with default key and Value
   [image: default key results]
3. Invoking with custom Host Key and Value
   [image: Custom Host Key and Value]

results: 404Not Found

please share solution or correct me if I am Wrong anywhere

Don't POST wrong Answers Please...

Comment: Stack Overflow Sites is a community of people where they dedicating their time & interest to provide the solutions for product/service users. One solution works for you and another solution works for others, which may not work to you. Accept the answer that worked to you. Else provide more details in the question or comments if answers not helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I have deployed an Admin Level Authorization Http Trigger to Azure Java Function app using VS Code:
[image]

As stated in the given vincentlauzon's [article](https://vincentlauzon.com/2017/12/04/azure-functions-http-authorization-levels/) of Azure Function App keys:
[image]

It only works with the master (host) key to Admin authorized functions in the Azure Function app:

[image]

Yes, there is a fault only in Admin Authorized Level Java 8.0 Versioned Azure Function Http Trigger that I have tested along with the different Authorization Levels and Java Versions 11, 17.0 Azure Functions are also tested and working successfully.

**Java 11.0 Version Azure Function Result**:

[image]

**Java 17.0 Version Azure Function Result**:

[image]

I have raised the ticket (No. [9010](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/9010)) in GitHub Azure Functions Host repository with all the test results where the MSFT backend team will check and provide the fix to it.

Comment: Hi Krishna, I tried Your solution it is not working ADMIN level auth But, same solution working for FUNCTION level auth....

Comment: Yes @Balu, what is the Java Version you're using. JAVA 8.0 has that problem - the same I have raised the ticket in the Azure Functions Host Official Issues repository and given the link at the end of the answer.

Comment: Using java 11...

Comment: If it is java 11, working fine as you can see the above practical screenshots in the answer